# Nodejs app throws cannot POST /users with body-parser middleware

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, body-parser

Here's my app.js file.

```
    var  express = require('express'),
     bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
     oauthServer = require('oauth2-server'),
     oauth_model = require('./app_modules/oauth_model')


const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

app.oauth = oauthServer({
  model: oauth_model, // See below for specification 
  grants: ['password', 'refresh_token'],
  debug: process.env.OAUTH_DEBUG,
  accessTokenLifetime: 172800,
  refreshTokenLifetime: 172800,
  authCodeLifetime: 120,


});


// Oauth endpoint.

app.all('/oauth/token', app.oauth.grant());


//  User registration endpoint.

app.post('/users', jsonParser, require('./routes/register.js'));


// Get user details.

app.get('/users', app.oauth.authorise(), require('./routes/users.js'));


app.post('/', app.oauth.authorise(), require('./routes/test.js'));

app.use(app.oauth.errorHandler());



app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Mixtra app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

When I send an invalid json body with POST request to `localhost:3000/users` the request goes to `register.js` and the validation code works there.

but strangely when I send  valid JSON body, it says "Cannot POST /users" with a 404 Not Found HTTP status code and nothing in terminal log.

Note: I'm using postman to send the api requests.

It would be really great if someone could help me with this.

Thanks,

Joy

Comment: use like this app.use(bodyParser.json()) instead of var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

Comment: I want to check for an invalid json in my register middleware and trow custom response, which is not working when I do `app.use(bodyParser.json())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see you using the `jsonParser`

You should use it before sending any json to it

```
app.use(jsonParser);
```

Comment: I'm using here:

`app.post('/users', jsonParser, require('./routes/register.js'));` as per the documentation.

Comment: also I want to check for an invalid json in my register middleware and trow custom response, which is not working when I do `app.use(bodyParser.json())`

like {"hello" : h23} is an invalid json which results in SyntaxError in my code instead of customized error.

Comment: I solved by using the JSON error library, but  looks like body-parser module doesn't invoke the next method. I'm not sure though. Here's my new code that worked.

`var  express = require('express'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  oauthServer = require('oauth2-server'),
  oauth_model = require('./app_modules/oauth_model'),
  jsonError =require('express-body-parser-json-error')

require('dotenv').config()

const app = express()

//routes.

var register = require('./routes/register.js')

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(jsonError())`